# Question on deriving $\diamond \alpha \rightarrow \diamond \diamond\alpha$ in modal logic S4-system

Tags: modal-logic

I can't seem to achieve this derivation.
The other way around, so $\diamond \diamond \alpha \rightarrow \diamond\alpha$, I did. But could someone helpt me with this part?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: I need to do a natural deduction on the S4 system, for the following: S4$\vdash \diamond \alpha \leftrightarrow \diamond \diamond \alpha$. I did the part from two diamond to one, but I can't figure out how to do the other way around

Comment: No, I mean: what's your background? How did the question arise? (we all like to know these things :-) What did you try already (apart from what you mentioned in the question)?

Comment: I am in my second year of Artificial Intellilgence, and at the moment I am following the course 'Logic for AI'.  I tried to solve this problem with the adjecent rules the S4-system gives, and with the $\diamond$ intro rule, but I get stuck every time.

Comment: This is just an instance of $\phi\to\Diamond\phi$, whose contrapositive $\Box\psi\to\psi$ is one of the standard axioms of S4.

Comment: We only get the following axioms for S4: system K and $ \box \alpha \rightarrow \apha $ and $ \box \alpha \rightarrow \box \box \alpha $

Comment: Well, good luck! I do suggest math.stackexchange, if you make the question fairly self contained and give the additional context it should make for a nice question.